# Unable to execute dex: GC overhead limit exceeded -> libraries

Tags: java, android, libraries

I needed to create new project of my existing previous. I copied src, res and manifest but when I import external libs (BugSense, AChartEngine) it wont start and I get

```
[2014-01-26 14:58:01 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: GC overhead limit exceeded
[2014-01-26 14:58:01 - MyApp] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

When I uncheck  `Android private libraries` in `Java Build Path / Order and Export` it runs in mobile device but it crashes on:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.bugsense.trace.BugSenseHandler
```

It worked well before.

Comment: You could try increasing Eclipse's heap space and see if that helps: http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_increase_the_heap_size_available_to_Eclipse%3F

Comment: It helps but I dont know why it suddenly needs so much memory

Answer (score 16, accepted):

go to your eclipse folder and find a file called eclipse.ini and change this

```
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
```

Comment: Accepted answer, although on Mac OS, eclipse.ini is not directly visible, but under "package contents" of the Eclipse executable.
Reference: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#-vm_value:_Mac_OS_X_Example